# How to approach feature selection for AFT survival models in R?

Tags: r, regression, survival

I can't seem to find much guidance on how to select features when implementing survival models. I have tried using the leaps package but I realised since I am dealing with censored observations, I may need to consider other approaches or is itstill okay to use the backward, forward or exhaustive feature search using Leaps?